# WSDL.exe tool - generating code for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, wsdl

Is the wsdl.exe tool capable of generating proxy code for .NET Compact Framework 2.0?

Regards
Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but .NET Compact Framework doesn't support all functionality generated by wsdl.exe.

For a description on how to filter out nonsupported features see this link-> [How to: Use a Proxy Generated by Wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229663.aspx)

Comment: Did you know you posted an old version of the link? Corrected.